# WPF TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"

Tags: wpf, textblock

I want to display text in italic with Segoe UI Light font family.

I am not sure but looks like in wpf TextBlock for FontFamily Segoe UI Light, FontStyle Italic is not supported. 
Is there any other control (Except RichTextBox because I want to use it for field name and value) like a label or something which I can use or am I doing something wrong.

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockContent"
               FontSize="28"
               FontStyle="Italic"
               FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
               Text="Text doesn't display in italic" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Segoe UI Light Italic font (you can get it from [Microsoft Typography](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1947)) and it comes as part of Windows 8. However, you need to have it installed on the machine in order to be able to use it.

Specifying the base font and applying the style should work if you have the font installed.

Specifying the font explicitly will definitely work:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockContent"
           FontSize="28"
           FontFamily="Segoe UI Light Italic"
           Text="Text should display in italic" />
```